# easiest way to expose an elastic load balancer to the internet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I've deployed grafana to to an AWS EKS cluster and I want to be able to access it from a web browser, if I create a Kubernetes service type of `LoadBalancer`, based on the very limited AWS networking knowledge I have, I know that this maps to an elastic load balancer, I can get the name of this, go to network and security -> network interfaces and get all the interfaces associated with this, one for each EC2 instance. Presuming its the public ip address associated with each ELB network interface I need to arrange access in order to access my grafana service, and again my AWS networking knowledge is very lacking, what is the fastest and easiest way for me to make the grafana Kubernetes service accessible via my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to expose any app running on kubernetes is to create a ServiceType as `LoadBalancer`.
I myself use the same for some of the services to get the things quickly up and running.
To get the loadbalancer name I do
`kubectl get svc`
which will give me the loadbalancer FQDN. I then map it to a DNS.

The other way which I use is to deploy the nginx-ingress-controller.

> https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws

This creates a ServiceType as `LoadBalancer`.
I then create the Ingress which will be mapped to the ingress controller elb.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

I use this for all my apps running with one `loadbalancer` mapping it to one elb using the nginx-ingress-controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific scenario, the solution was to open up the port for the LoadBalancer service via a port.